# PostgreSQL: get input parameters as row values

Tags: postgresql, syntax, plpgsql

I have created a simple function:

```
create function my fucnction(uuid, uuid, date) returns boolean as
$$
    select ... from t where t.f1 = $1 and t.f2 = $2 and t.f3 = $3;
$$
language sql stable;
```

It would be great syntax-wise if I could access the input parameters as a single row (which would be equal to `($1, $2, $3)` in my function), so I could write:

```
create function my fucnction(uuid, uuid, date) returns boolean as
$$
    select ... from t where (t.f1, t.f2, t.f3) = <the input parameters row>;
$$
language sql stable;
```

which would be equal to:

```
create function my fucnction(uuid, uuid, date) returns boolean as
$$
    select ... from t where (t.f1, t.f2, t.f3) = ($1, $2, $3);
$$
language sql stable;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `...where (t.f1, t.f2, t.f3) = ($1, $2, $3);` This should work. Did you tested and it not works?

Comment: That works great. But I am looking for a syntax replacement for `($1, $2, $3)`. Something like `NEW` and `OLD` which can be used in triggers. Does that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. I am a big fan of the [`row()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) function, especially in `count(distinct row())` queries.

```
create OR REPLACE function my_function(text,text,text) returns bigint as
$$
    select count(*) from t where row(t1,t2,t3) = row($1,$2,$3);
$$
language sql stable;

select * from my_function('a','b','c');
```

NOTE: this seems to work with your syntax of `(t1,t2,t3)`, as well.

**EDIT:** I may have misunderstood your question.  If you particularly want a named reference like in triggers, you can always pass in a record type (here I am using the type defined by table `t`).  It might be worth looking into the [`record` datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) as well as *PLPGSQL* if you need a more complex function:

```
create OR REPLACE function my_function(blast t) returns bigint as
$$

    select count(*) from t where (t1,t2,t3) = blast;
$$
language sql stable;

select * from my_function(row('a','b','c'));
```

One last [alternative](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html) - does not give the niceness of the syntax above, presumably because the type is not defined, but if you need separate parameters on input:

```
create OR REPLACE function my_function(_1 text, _2 text, _3 text) returns bigint as
$$

    select count(*) from t where (t1,t2,t3) = (my_function._1, my_function._2, my_function._3);
$$
language sql stable;

select * from my_function('a','b','c')
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, I guess `select count(*) from t where (t1,t2,t3) = blast` will work then?

Comment: Correct - just confirmed.  One more alternative I will add, but does not give you the nice `where (t1,t2,t3) = blast`.

Comment: Thanks! I did now know `row()`, seems very handy. I will accept after your edit!